# Laravel advanced middlewares

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin, middleware

I'm using this line in some controller's __construct

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

This results, that every not logged user will be redirected to login page. It's of course, ok, but there is a problem.

I have two groups of users. In database I have a column called "role", which is boolean. 0 means basic users and 1 means admins. How can I treat, that entrance to some of controllers will be allowed only for admins? I really don't know how to do that in pretty way.

Comment: Create your own middleware:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Then just pass in that middleware to your controller or route for those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass things to the middleware, like

```
$this->middleware('auth:1');
```

Now in the middleware you can check to see if the authenticated user has a role that you passed (in the example, 1). If they don't have the role that you require, then you can redirect them to the login screen or however you want to handle it.

Comment: Where can I set, that auth:1 means role==1?

Comment: @MegoSoft the auth part is the middleware, the part after the colon is the information passed to the middleware. So you would add a parameter to your auth middleware’s handle method that represents this. That is what you use for your role validation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get the authenticated user and then write custom logic.

```
         if(Auth::user()->role==0)
         {
           //you are basic user
          }
          esle if(Auth->user()->role==1)
          {
          //you are admin
          }
```

you can also Gates and Policies for this type of work.